# IIS 6.0 https not working "connection was reset"

Tags: iis-6, ssl-certificate, https

Application Server Windows Server 2003 SP2 with IIS 6.0

IIS has a "Default Web Site" (port 18000, ssl 443, ID=1) with a certificate created by me.
I have an specific site called "scj.galaxy.Weekly" (port 80, ssl 443, ID=1272369728) that is working fine. I have an entry in windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts that links galaxy.Weekly.scjdev.ds to the server ip in both my local machine and in the application Server.

These sites works:

**http://scj.galaxy.weekly/test.html** works

**http://scj.galaxy.weekly/test.aspx** works

But

**https://scj.galaxy.weekly/test.html** fails

Error message is:

> The connection was reset The
>   connection to the server was reset
>   while the page was loading.

The certificate was working fine for months. It was created with something similar to this:

> Selfssl /N:CN=*.scjdev.ds /V:3650
>   /S:1 /P:443

I have tried several options and none of them are working:

- 1) Create a certificate only in "Default
  Web Site" and link it to
  SecureBindings with command prompt

> cscript adsutil.vbs set
>   /w3svc/1272369728/SecureBindings ":443:galaxy.Weekly.scjdev.ds"

- 2) Create a certificate only in
  "Galaxy Site" and link it to
  SecureBindings
- 3) Create a certificate in both and link
  them to secureBindings.

**Probably I am missing an step or something, but I can't see it.**

Here is the relevant config of Galaxy Site:

```
<IIsWebServer   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1272369729"
        AuthFlags="0"
        LogPluginClsid="{FF160663-DE82-11CF-BC0A-00AA006111E0}"
        SSLCertHash="c36a514a0be90fbc121d9c19bb052842289d5aee"
        SSLStoreName="MY"
        SecureBindings=":443:galaxy.Weekly.scjdev.ds"
        ServerAutoStart="TRUE"
        ServerBindings=":80:galaxy.Weekly.scjdev.ds"
        ServerComment="galaxy.Weekly.scjdev.ds"
    >
</IIsWebServer>

<IIsWebVirtualDir   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/1272369729/root"
        AccessFlags="AccessRead | AccessScript"
        AppFriendlyName="Default Application"
        AppIsolated="2"
        AppRoot="/LM/W3SVC/1272369729/Root"
        AuthFlags="AuthAnonymous | AuthNTLM"
        DefaultDoc="Default.aspx"
        DirBrowseFlags="EnableDirBrowsing | DirBrowseShowDate | DirBrowseShowTime | DirBrowseShowSize | DirBrowseShowExtension | DirBrowseShowLongDate"
        Path="D:\Webs\Galaxysite"
        ScriptMaps="some config... "
    >
</IIsWebVirtualDir>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it finally removing ALL the certificates and stopping ALL the sites when creating the new one.

**The key thing is stopping ALL the sites.** If you fail to do so, an internal reference will kept hooked, everything will seem ok but will fail when trying to browse any page with https.